# How do I update group list Textview from Child of that group?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have following code, it is for a simple Expandable listview.

My question is: I want to update my group text view when I click any child of that group.

Group list xml is as follow:
group_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSelectedChildCount"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Raw list xml is as follow:
raw_item_list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRawitem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgItemSelect"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_radio_off"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

//  My Expandable Adapter is as follow:
   // here in getChildView, I want to update group view

```
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, 
           View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = 
        (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService
        (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list,null);

        }


        TextView txtSelectedChildCount = 
           (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtSelectedChildCount);
        return view;
    }


        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {



        if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = 
            (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService
            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_item_list,null);
        }

        final ImageView imgItemSelect = 
            (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgItemSelect);


        imgItemSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // if clicked here then increment group text count
            // txtSelectedChildCount.setText("incremented count = " + count);
            // count is local variable in adapter

        }
        });

        return view;
    }
```